# ERROR filter bad words in input and saving to SQL

Tags: php, html, sql-server, input-filtering

I have a form in which I want to allow only text and number fields: my input filter will not allow `$%^&*()_`.

I wrote the following code:

### Input filter

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="for.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="textinput" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Sanoj Lawrence" class="form-control input-md" onkeyup="validate();">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        </form>
        <script>
            $(function() {//<-- wrapped here
                $('.form-control').on('input', function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@ ]/g, ''); //<-- replace all other than given set of values
                });
            });
        </script>
```

and this works well.

**My problem is** that I need to filter bad words and save the input text to a database. I wrote following code to save to a database:

### Form processing code

```
<?php

$text = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
$text = preg_replace_callback('!\w+!', 'filter_bad_words', $text);
echo $text;

$bad_words = array(
    'word1' => 'se x',
    'word2' => 'SEX',
    'word1' => 's e x',
    'word1' => 's E x',
    'word1' => 'se X',
);

function filter_bad_words($matches) {
    global $bad_words;
    $replace = $bad_words[$matches[0]];
    return isset($replace) ? $replace : $matches[0];
}

$db_password = '123456';
$db_username = 'sanoj';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO filter (cat) VALUES (:cat)');
$data->execute(array(':cat' => $text,))
?>
```

I am using the above code to save the text to the database, but BAD WORD FILTER  dosen't works it saves input as user enters `bad_word_filter does't works` i.e. the field is created in the database and filter word is saved. i don't want filter word to be saved to `SQL`

Could some one please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the comma `$text,` <=

Comment: What could be happening is the use of `INPUT_POST`, which may be looking for a POST method in a form and a named element. Do you have form tags, or are you using what you posted? Are you getting anything back with `echo $text;`?

Comment: Pro tip: your filter is useless at best

Comment: @Fred-ii- `echo $text;` also not displaying anything i typed sex game and i need only game to be saved to sql so i made above filter and does't works

Comment: As I said, if you do not have form tags containing a POST method, chances are, that could be the reason why your code is failing. Here is an example http://runnable.com/Um5fxavjGgRTAADo/how-to-validate-input-variables-using-filter_input-function-

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have post method

Comment: Then show your full HTML form code. Also, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- cleared bug but bad word filter doesn't works

Comment: @creator I've posted something below.

Comment: Don't even bother trying to filter out words that you deem to be offensive, it can be easily circumvented and will just annoy your users. Aside from which, since when is 'sex' a bad word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't fix your present code (as much as I tried), but am submitting the following suggestive method, using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string = $_POST['name'];
$words = array('se x', 'SEX', 's e x');
$replacements = array('censored 1', 'censored 2', 'censored 3');

$result = str_replace($words, $replacements, $string);

echo $result;
```

---

**Edit:**

```
$input = 'sE x';

$filtered_list = array(
    'sex',
    'sE x',
    'SEX',
);

$replaced = 'beep';
$filtered = str_replace($filtered_list, $replaced, $input);

echo $filtered;
```

Comment: i don't want to use `$_POST['name'];` can i replace with this`filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);`

Comment: @creator It was an example. You can pass that variable to a filter.

Comment: it works can you please tell what's wrong in my code added in question

Comment: @creator That's just it; I couldn't figure out why, which is why I posted my *alternate/suggestive* answer. If I had been able to fix it, only then would I have been able to explain why.

Comment: a small bug there are three words in `$words = array('se x', 'SEX', 's e x');` and 3 replacement words in replacement array i need to add n number of words in `$words = array(` and i need to replace only beep as replacement word

Comment: @creator I've tested my code above using any of those 3 words with no issues.

Comment: my issues is , i just changed this line like this `$replacements = array('beep');` can you please change and try

Comment: @creator I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @creator Reload my answer and see under **Edit**. My initial answer did indeed answer your question, since you did say it worked. Your second request for a different method constituted as another question.

Comment: Alright Fred, long time no speak - did I ever tell you that I was born in the county of Esbeep, England? ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog Aye, mate. Not sure if you did, but yeah... Esbeep's a nice place. *Cheers* - Oh, yeah... when is 'sex' a bad word? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I thought the penny would drop eventually ;) Have a good Christmas fella.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Cheers! Thanks, and have a good Christmas too :) Enjoy yourself